# Make: *** No targerts specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -ansi 

reversepoetry : reversepoetry.o 
    $(CC) -o reversepoetry reversepoetry.o 

reversepoetry.o : reversepoetry.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c reversepoetry.c 
run: 
    $./reversepoetry  
clean:
    rm reversepoetry reversepoetry.o
```

I'm having trouble running this make file. the only things in the directory is makefile.txt and reversepoetry.c 
I type $ make and I get the error posted in the title

Comment: Remove the `.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The makefile should be called `Makefile`, not `makefile.txt`.

Comment: Or you can do `make -f makefile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says “no makefile found”. This means it isn’t seeing your file. According to [the GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names), it by default looks for `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile`, in that order; they suggest you call your file `Makefile`. None of these have an extension.

It also says what to do if you’re sure you want to use a nonstandard name for the makefile:

> If you want to use a nonstandard name for your makefile, you can specify the makefile name with the ‘`-f`’ or ‘`--file`’ option. The arguments ‘`-f` *name*’ or ‘`--file=`*name*’ tell make to read the file *name* as the makefile. If you use more than one ‘`-f`’ or ‘`--file`’ option, you can specify several makefiles. All the makefiles are effectively concatenated in the order specified. The default makefile names `GNUmakefile`, `makefile` and `Makefile` are not checked automatically if you specify ‘`-f`’ or ‘`--file`’.

Therefore, you should either rename your makefile to `Makefile` with no extension, or call `make` with `make -f makefile.txt`. You should strongly prefer the first option, because anybody else who looks at your code will expect it. Besides a makefile isn’t really a plain-text natural-language file solely for humans like the `.txt` usually implies.